# Add classes to multiple HTML elements with a loop

Tags: css, loops

I'm creating a color wheel that has 360 colors. The gist of my markup looks like this:

HTML:

```
<table class="table1">
  <td class="medium-grey"></td>
  <td class="charcoal"></td>
  <td class="black"></td>
  ...
```

CSS:

```
.medium-grey { background-color: #76878e; }
.charcoal { background-color: #534259; }
.black { background-color: #060807; }
```

I am adding a background color via CSS to each `td`. I have **alot** of colors to manually add to each table and am finding this cumbersome. I am curious if there's a way I can loop through groups of colors to append to  `td` classes with javascript or sass mixins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var css_classes =['medium-grey' , 'charcoal', 'black'];

var idx = 0
$( "table.table1 td" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).addClass(css_classes[idx]);
    if (idx < css_classes.length-1){
      idx+=1;
    }else{
      idx = 0;
    }
});
```

given css classes, iterate td, and assign css classes in order.

refer to : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16godohe/1/)

Comment: Baller. This is what I wanted